# Fruit Selection Question

Tags: permutations, combinations

The question is: 
A bag contains 2 Apples, 3 Oranges and 4 Bananas. The number of ways in which 3 fruits can be selected if at least one banana is always present in the combination (Assume fruit of same species to be alike) is:

I am getting answer 7 but the correct answer is 6.

My approach:

1) if there is only one banana present in the combination then number of such type of combination would be

Now, the rest two fruits can be alike or different. 
So if the fruits are alike we can select from the rest in 2C1 ways or if the fruits are different then also we can select in 2C1 ways.

2) if there are two banana present in the combinations then we can select one fruit in 2C1 ways.

3) This case includes where all the selected fruits are banana so it would be 1

which totals upto 7

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: "*the rest two fruits can be alike or different... if the fruits are different then we can select in 2C1 ways*"  How?  Why?  With exactly one banana and two more fruits with both of the extra two fruits being different they must be one apple and one orange.  There is no other possibility, what second possibility are you seeing?  (*remember, an apple and an orange is the same thing as an orange and an apple here*)

Comment: @JMoravitz You are right, Good observation. Thanks for helping me out!